curl_easy_cleanup() causes Segfault- why?
I have a function which reads from an url and writes to a file.
I am getting a segfault when calling the curl_easy_cleanup(). I uncommented this call and I am not getting the segfault any more.
someone having an idea why I am getting a segfault?
Compiler call:
root@zentrale:/root# cc -rdynamic -Wall -g  -lcurl -o Beispiel beispiel.c

This is the code including a full program to show its behaviour:
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int get_2file(char *url, char *filename )


{
CURL *curl_handle;
FILE *FI;
int r,code;
 
code = 0; r=0;
/* init the curl session iand set url*/ 
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url); 
FI = fopen(filename, "w");
if(FI) {
    /* write the page body to this file handle */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, FI);
    r = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    if (r != 0) {
        code = -1;
    }
    r = fclose(FI);
} else {
    code=-1;
}
/* cleanup curl stuff */ 
curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
return code;
}
char *url="https://www.knebb.de/files/text.txt";
char *jsonfile="/tmp/wetter.test";
int ret;

ret=get_2file(url,jsonfile); 
printf("ret ist: %d.\n",ret);
return 0;
}


strace result (only last lines):
getdents64(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(5)                                = 0
getrandom("\xd6\x4d\x5f\x3a\x12\x6d\x04\xc5\xce\xf3\x0f\x14\x88\xf0\x5a\x13\xbf\xbf\xea\xab\xdd\xb8\x41\x04\x0b\xe8\x81\x86\xb2\xdc\x87\xb3"..., 64, 0) = 64
send(4, "\26\3\1\0\356\1\0\0\352\3\3\207XL\343\231\301\340\212\314\367\340\343\21\354\35\232X\262F\0R"..., 243, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 243
recv(4, 0x16d820b, 5, 0)                = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLRDNORM}])
recv(4, "\26\3\3\0p", 5, 0)             = 5
recv(4, "\2\0\0l\3\3j\247'\311\215\246\312kWT\351\303\370\230\37\n\204\240E\37\26$\7\375DO"..., 112, 0) = 112
recv(4, "\26\3\3\26/", 5, 0)            = 5
recv(4, "\v\0\26+\0\26(\0\6J0\202\6F0\202\5.\240\3\2\1\2\2\21\0\351\35\27\266\342\r"..., 5679, 0) = 5422
recv(4, "\0\10V\374\2\360\233\350\377\244\372\326{\306D\200\316O\304\305\366\0X\314\246\266\274\24Ih\4v"..., 257, 0) = 257
recv(4, "\26\3\3\1,", 5, 0)             = 5
recv(4, "\f\0\1(\3\0\35 ;;\375\337\310n^\275H'\315\356\346\246\303\207\200\313\3434\304\2W\374"..., 300, 0) = 300
recv(4, "\26\3\3\0\4", 5, 0)            = 5
recv(4, "\16\0\0\0", 4, 0)              = 4
send(4, "\26\3\3\0%\20\0\0! \2308\22G\27\374a\36\25\307F\346v,F0G\211\37\361\215<"..., 42, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 42
send(4, "\24\3\3\0\1\1", 6, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 6
send(4, "\26\3\3\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\n1CR.t\326\202\221\252\16\220\177\35y\251%>\233"..., 45, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 45
recv(4, 0x16d8203, 5, 0)                = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLRDNORM}])
recv(4, "\24\3\3\0\1", 5, 0)            = 5
recv(4, "\1", 1, 0)                     = 1
recv(4, "\26\3\3\0(", 5, 0)             = 5
recv(4, "\232H\34\311}\23\302\203V\223w\350\21\305\356\313G\342\24.\311r\351\\\327\301,\212\253\2560#"..., 40, 0) = 40
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2335, ...}) = 0
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2335, ...}) = 0
read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2335
_llseek(5, -1476, [859], SEEK_CUR)      = 0
read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1476
close(5)                                = 0
send(4, "\27\3\3\0\324\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1@L\317\304\325\343\360o.Zg\276!m\213>*e/"..., 217, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 217
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN|POLLRDNORM}])
recv(4, "\27\3\38r", 5, 0)              = 5
recv(4, "\232H\34\311}\23\302\204\206w\346c\372T-\327\201\263\350\206Y\4\221j\243i\335\337+3\246B"..., 14450, 0) = 7235
recv(4, "\324U\1t\211\274\346\16\314\343\260\16\242\2<A\276\3218\240\253=P!\275%2\332\24\224:\\"..., 7215, 0) = 1448
recv(4, ";\215\371\347\320\243\273\21~\311\23B\243/\372\3258$\316\275\271C\22-N-a\6a\276;s"..., 5767, 0) = 1448
recv(4, "\334\263\2143O\353\377\346\\n\37\0\331x\226\33\260\344\375\262\227\343\26\315^\345\221\10q\326\334\267"..., 4319, 0) = 2896
recv(4, "\r\335\273'\31J\323\305f\22\203Sq,i\275\203\360\274n*.\330\f\260\271\v%\314\nY\314"..., 1423, 0) = 1423
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(3, "{\"lat\":53.4731,\"lon\":13.2316,\"ti"..., 12288) = 12288
write(3, "\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"descrip"..., 1761) = 1761
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xd6ed9fc8} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Speicherzugriffsfehler



And the function does. It calls the provided url and write what it gets into /tmp/wetter.test. Even when there is a segfault I can see the file is created and written with proper content. I do not need to set further curl options. According to it's docs I can leave it as defaults.

Oh, and shouldn't you #include <syslog.h> ? Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Please add the stack trace from the SIGSEGV.

Cannot reproduce. Do you have this behaviour when you run the exact same program you have shown here?

Standard C does not allow nested function definitions.

Why does the function return a long if the only possible values are 0 and -1? Why not return a bool?

Fixed all your suggestions (long int, copy&paste code from my Linux box, added compiler-calls).
Still the same. I am not sure about the proper use of strace so I simply added the results as well.

What version of libcurl are you using? Try updating it, it could be an old bug or one introduced by an OS patch.

Might be outdated, but I can not upgrade the OS on this device.
libcurl 7.64.0-4+deb10u9

as not even the simplest example did work I tried on a different box. There it worked fine!
I did apt --purge remove libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcurl3-gnutls and installed it again.
Since then the program is running fine!
Greetings
Christian
